# libxml2 parsing docs with indentation

Tags: c, xml, libxml2

I'm trying to debug code that is parsing an xml document that contains indentation. I'm trying to figure out the right parameters to use on the xmlReadMemory function.

What does the XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS option do on the following method call?

```
xmlReadMemory(buffer.data, (int)buffer.size, "noname.xml", NULL, XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS);
```

Does the XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS option instruct that it will simply ignore whitespace (new lines and indentation)?

I've searched Google and can't find any meaningful documentation for this.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [docs](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html), it just removes blank nodes..

`XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS = 256 : remove blank nodes`

If I had to guess, a blank node is one where [xmlIsBlankNode()](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlIsBlankNode) returns a positive result.  The description is:

`Checks whether this node is an empty or whitespace only (and possibly ignorable) text-node.`

Comment: And what is a blank node?