# What does LIBXML_NOBLANKS do, exactly?

Tags: php, xml-parsing, html-parsing, libxml2

What is the difference between

```php
$domd=new DOMDocument();
$domd->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
```

and

```php
$domd=new DOMDocument();
$domd->loadHTML($html, 0);
```

?

edit: just in case someone wants to remove all empty+whitespace text nodes (which is not exactly what LIBXML_NOBLANKS does), here's a function to do just that,

```php
$removeAnnoyingWhitespaceTextNodes = function (\DOMNode $node) use (&$removeAnnoyingWhitespaceTextNodes): void {
    if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
        // Warning: it's important to do it backwards; if you do it forwards, the index for DOMNodeList might become invalidated;
        // that's why i don't use foreach() - don't change it (unless you know what you're doing, ofc)
        for ($i = $node->childNodes->length - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
            $removeAnnoyingWhitespaceTextNodes($node->childNodes->item($i));
        }
    }
    if ($node->nodeType === XML_TEXT_NODE && !$node->hasChildNodes() && !$node->hasAttributes() && (strlen(trim($node->textContent)) === 0)) {
        //echo "Removing annoying POS";
        // var_dump($node);
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    } //elseif ($node instanceof DOMText) { echo "not removed"; var_dump($node, $node->hasChildNodes(), $node->hasAttributes(), trim($node->textContent)); }
};
$dom=new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$removeAnnoyingWhitespaceTextNodes($dom);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `LIBXML_NOBLANKS` parser option removes all text nodes containing only whitespace. Consider the following document, for example:

```
<doc>
    <elem>text</elem>
</doc>
```

Normally, the element `doc` has three children: A whitespace text node, the element `elem` and another whitespace text node. When parsing with `LIBXML_NOBLANKS`, the `doc` element will only have a single element child.

Comment: makes sense, but that can't be the whole story, take ```<doc><elem> </elem></doc>``` - the single whitespace in the elem makes libxml create a textNode containing only whitespace, even with LIBXML_NOBLANKS, see https://3v4l.org/gXHvV

Comment: @hanshenrik Right, there seems to be an exception if the "blank" node is the only child. Unfortunately, this isn't properly documented anywhere. You'd have to look at the source code.

Answer (score 1):

Probably:

> `LIBXML_NOBLANKS` Removes all insignificant whitespace within the document.

However I found no clear sign that this (borrowed) description fits 100% to what in [the PHP documentation is written](https://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php#constant.libxml-noblanks):

> **`LIBXML_NOBLANKS`** (int)
>
> Remove blank nodes

Which wondered me and I guess [the reference here is to libxml2](https://web.archive.org/web/20200707090006/http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS):

> `XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS = 256 : remove blank nodes`

And I could find more Q&A accessible in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18521956/367456 and it seems that this is probably different to *insignificant whitespace*.